# tableHeaderView disappeared after rotating the screen

Tags: objective-c, ios8, tableheader

I want to show the table header/footer (not section's) in a view controller embedded in the navigation bar, so in `viewDidLoad` I add this: https://gist.github.com/romyilano/5035458. 

It seems worked. But, when I rotate the screen, the header disappeared! Reason unknown? What I use: Xcode7+iOS8+Obj-C. Any ideas? 

At the very beginning, everything is OK. 

[image]

After rotating the screen, the header is disappeared!

[image]

Comment: Yes, use autolayout, and all the elements in this view had added the constraints needed.

Comment: [check this... might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989254/ios-6-0-autolayout-issue-with-constraints-subviews-disappear-when-rotated)

Comment: Feeling embarrassed, it turns out that someone add this method [-viewWillTransitionToSize: withTransitionCoordinator:](https://gist.github.com/marcoarment/1105553afba6b4900c10) to the implementation, but without calling it...Even not be called, it can also take effect. (But why?) Thanks for your concerning @FahimParkar